# Iframe jQuery won't execute in Internet Explorer [All versions]

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, iframe

I have a webpage that includes an iframe linked to another page on the same site and domain. This iframe page generates a chart via Google Charts and works perfectly well in all browsers except IE (I'm using 11 but it doesn't work in any of them).

I have pinpointed the problem down to jQuery not running (this is used to set up the data for the chart) in this iframe. Vanilla JS will run but as soon as jQuery is used, it falls flat on its face.

The iframe page has jQuery included locally and no errors are displayed in Internet Explorer's developer tools. Would anyone have any inkling on what would be causing this strange error? I'm currently using jQuery 1.10.1 but tried older versions to no avail.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Upgrade to a newer version of jquery. 1.10.2, or the beta of the next release. I remember reading a related bug report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in jQuery 1.10.1, upgrade to 1.10.2 or 2.0.3 to fix.

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13980

http://blog.jquery.com/2013/07/03/jquery-1-10-2-and-2-0-3-released/

Lucky for you there were no syntax changes between the two, meaning the upgrade should go smoothly.

Comment: Fantastic! Can't believe I hadn't thought of that, thanks for your help